# Как изменить имя приложения в django?

Tags: django

Здравствуйте. Есть приложение `articles`. Нужно, чтобы в админке отображалось на русском "Содержание", например.
Пробовал так:
В папке с приложением в apps.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
# articles/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ArticleAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "Содержание"
    verbose_name = "Содержание"
```

После в папке с приложением в `__init__.py`:

```
# articles/__init__.py

default_app_config = "articles.apps.ArticleAppConfig"
```

Сервер на старте выдает ошибку:

> ImportError: No module named Содержание

Будьте так добры)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в указании имени приложения:

```
class ArticleAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "articles"    #имя вашего приложения
    verbose_name = u"Содержание"  #желаемое имя для отображения
```

Comment: Спасибо. Так можно изменить имя объектов. Я так и делаю. Мне необходимо изменить имя приложения.

Comment: @Coveraver нашел ошибку в вашем коде, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас наше приложение HOUSES на англ. языке, исправим.

Откроем файл apps.py внутри папки `houses`, добавим внутри класса `HousesConfig` поле `verbose_name` со значением “дома”.

Python2
Если возникает ошибка:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character
>   (no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html)

то нужно добавить строчку:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class HousesConfig(AppConfig):
      name = 'houses'
      verbose_name = "дома"
```

А затем в файле `__init__.py` в той же папке, создадим переменную:

```
default_app_config = “houses.apps.HousesConfig”
```

Перезапускаем сервер. Все получилось.

Подробнее по этой [ссылке](http://vswebschool.blogspot.ru/2016/09/django-7.html).